# Is performing a "concurrent reduction" productive when the result is of type Map (not ConcurrentHashMap)?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am reading the Java document about `stream`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

The `Reduction, concurrency, and ordering` section is confusing:
[image]

I have stated my question in the screenshot. In short, is it meaningful to use concurrent reduction when the result type is `Map` instead of `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` is an interface while `ConcurrentHashMap` is an implementation. The point that they try to bring across is that the implementation should be able to handle concurrent writes/deposits/puts. It should be thread safe since it will be accessed from different thread when used in parallel. If you had a different implementation which is also thread safe that would work just as will.

Comment: Got it. So the `collect` method will return different implementations of `Map` based on the characters of the stream and collector. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can already read what it means to [programming to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), it will help you understand the concept.

In this case, you can find the return type easily by doing one of the following things

### Code

```
List<Integer> integers = List.of(1, 2, 3);

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sequential = integers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()));
System.out.println("sequential.getClass() = " + sequential.getClass());

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> parallel = integers.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(Function.identity()));
System.out.println("parallel.getClass() = " + parallel.getClass());
```

Prints

```
sequential.getClass() = class java.util.HashMap
parallel.getClass() = class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
```

Means that `ConcurrentHashMap` is indeed used

### JDK Sources

You can see the implementation used is `ConcurrentHashMap`

```
public static <T, K> Collector<T, ?, ConcurrentMap<K, List<T>>>
    groupingByConcurrent(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier) {
        return groupingByConcurrent(classifier, ConcurrentHashMap::new, toList());
    }
```

But pay attention to this as it can change in the future to another implementation. This is made very clear in the javadoc of this `Collector`

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, or serializability of the `ConcurrentMap` or `List` objects returned, or of the thread-safety of the `List` objects returned.